# Oracle Forms: How to pass variable between windows by popup menu

Tags: oracle, oracleforms, popupmenu

I have created a form for a master table, now I want to open another form displaying the details when right click a field and choose "Details".

How could I get the "ITEM ORDER" and pass the value to the new form to show the related information ? If it's not stated clearly, please comment. Thanks

[image: Example picture]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the parameters of call_form or open_form procedure is a parameter list.
You use this parameter list to pass parameters. On the calling form:

1. create a parameter list
2. add the parameter to the param
3. call_form using this parameter list:

> ```
> DECLARE
>     fParams ParamList := null;
> BEGIN 
>   fParams := Get_Parameter_List('SOME_NAME'); 
>   IF (not Id_Null(fParams)) THEN 
>     destroy_parameter_list(fList);
>   END IF;
>
>   fParams := Create_Parameter_List('SOME_NAME');
>   Add_Parameter(fParams, 'PARAM_NAME', TEXT_PARAMETER, 'PARAM_VALUE'); 
>   OPEN_FORM('Form_Name', ACTIVATE, SESSION, NO_SHARE_LIBRARY_DATA, fParams);
> END;
> ```

On the Called Form:
You must declare the parameter on the Parameters section, with **the same name** as the one used in add_parameter. After that you can reference the parameter by using `:parameter.param_name.`

One word of caution: You **can not** use `:parameter` in the where clause of data blocks. Copy the parameter to another data block item and use this one.